# Count the number of times that a binary subset appears in a list of lists, Python

Tags: python, list, subset

I'm trying to figure it out a way to count the number of times that a subset appears in a list of lists. For example if I have the following list:

```py
dataset = [[0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0]]
```

The pattern `[0,0,1,0,1,0]` appears in three of the four items of the list (i.e. in three of the lists, the elements at index 2 and index 4 are set to 1, just like in the pattern). How can I count the number of times that the pattern appears?

So far I've tried this, but it does not work:

```py
subsets_count = []
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    current_subset_count = 0
    for j in range(len(dataset)):
        if dataset[i] in dataset[j]:
            subset_count += 1

    subsets_count.append(current_subset_count)
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question? `[0,0,1,0,1,0]` only appears once, but your description says it shows up three times.

Comment: yes, that parttern also appears in indexes 1 and 2 of the main list, without taking into account the items that don't belong to the subset

Comment: I only see the pattern repeating once. By subset, do you mean that we can skip elements?

Comment: yes, just taking into account the items of the target list to find how many times that pattern repeats in the other sublists

Comment: Can you mark where these patterns exist in the sublists? I don't see them.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark sure, in the second item of the list the partten appears in the position 2 and 4, and in the third item of the list the pattern appears also in the 2 and 4 positions respectively, but in the fourth item there is only a 1 in the second position and a 0 in the fourth position, hence the pattern does not exist in the fourth item of the list

Comment: Oh, got it. Writing an answer now.

Comment: Also to sum 1 to the counter, the pattern has to respect original the position of the subset, in this case that in position 2 and 4 of an item, there is necessarily a one

Comment: @matikuto Can you edit your post to remove any references to the term "pattern" and use something like "required indices", and then say something like "In the 1D list, the elements at index 2 and 4 are set to 1, just like the sublists at indices 0, 1, and 2 of `dataset`".

Comment: What's the desired result, exactly? The list `[3,1,1,1]`?

Comment: You say "binary", so... all numbers are 0 or 1, right?

Answer (score 2):

For each sublist, generate a set of indices where the ones exist. Do the same for the pattern. Then, for each set of indices, find whether the pattern indices are a subset of that set. If so, the pattern is in the sublist.

```py
one_indices_of_subsets = [{i for i, v in enumerate(sublist) if v} for sublist in dataset]
pattern_indices = {i for i, v in enumerate(pattern) if v}

result = sum(1 for s in one_indices_of_subsets if pattern_indices <= s)

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
3
```

Comment: For one pattern, this seems like overkill, and for all patterns (like they're trying in their code), you don't need separate code to do the same thing for the current pattern again. Could btw use `compress` here as well (together with `count`). Not sure if better, I just love `compress`.

Comment: Oh and better use a subset operator instead of the intersection thingy.

Comment: @KellyBundy Fixed the subset operator thing. What do you mean by "overkill"?

Comment: I meant building the sets just to use them once. Though thinking about it again, I now realize that the set for the pattern is used multiple times. And requires computing sets for the others to make use of it. Still feels heavy, but less so than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

Using one of my favorite itertools, [compress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
[sum(all(compress(e, d)) for e in dataset)
 for d in dataset]
```

Results in ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BCsMgEEX3nmKWCi4i3XTTkwQXUg0R1JFxsujprU3aEDqfWTw@vF9fvGK53Sv1vhBmiByIEVODmCsSwxNzpdCaEN6xa4HhAfM86Umb462@kBlk/jqz04i1QgzVlnZH27J0KcnfgAwavFKwIEGAWOC7pwSc9@n8pRvCSrGwPLSq9zc)):

```
[3, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: This also works with `all(map(le, d, e))` instead of `all(compress(e,d))` (with `from operator import le`)

Comment: @Stef Right... actually I think my very first idea was `<=` in a genexp. But I didn't think of using `operator` here. Still I like `compress` better, and it should be faster for a few reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This allows for one digit to be different from the pattern.
Straight forward pattern matcher:

```
dataset = [[0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0]]

pattern = [0,0,1,0,1,0]
m = len(pattern)
subsets_count = 0

for i in range(len(dataset)):
    count = 0
    for j in range(m):
        if dataset[i][j] == pattern[j]:
            count +=1
    if count >= m-1:
        subsets_count +=1

print(subsets_count)
```

Output:
3

Comment: i noticed and fixed my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count a pattern (by taking into account the order of the pattern) you can simply use the `.count()` function by applying it as follows:

```
dataset = [[0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0]]

num_count = dataset.count([0,0,1,0,1,0])

print(num_count)
```

output:

```
2
```

and if you dont care about the order of the 0's and ones, you can use:

```
dataset = [[0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0]]

num_count = [sum(el) for el in dataset].count(sum([0,0,1,0,1,0]))

print(num_count)
```

output2:

```
3
```

Comment: OP states that the answer should be three, but this code outputs two.

Comment: does the order of the ones and zeros matter ? if not use the second part of the code.

Comment: I don't know, but I'm not sure why you're making this assumption (besides the fact that it makes the answer correct for this particular input).

Comment: `sum()` seems like a bad choice. `[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` also sums to `2` as does `[1,1]`. That doesn't seem to be a pattern match in any sense.

Comment: In the dataset in my example the pattern clearly is repeated twice, so it is weird that the code doesn't work for you, can you give us more details about what's being asked ?

Comment: @Mark I made that assumption just in the second part of my example because the example provided in the topic isn't clear enough (says its repeated 3 of four times, which is not ..)

Comment: The question is not clear enough — it should probably be closed unless the OP clarifies what they mean. Answering it based on assumptions doesn't really anyone.

Comment: @Mark It's answerable, it's just that "pattern" is a bit misleading. It's about subsets of indices where there's a one. This answer doesn't answer the original question though.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's answerable now that it's been clarified. It wasn't before.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. I'm not sure what terms I'd use here -- I suggested some above, but I feel like you could do better. "Pattern" is an understandable but unfortunately confusing choice. Oh well ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
dataset = [
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
]

pat = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

cnt = sum(all(a == b for a, b in zip(pat, d) if a == 1) for d in dataset)
print(cnt)
```

Prints:

```
3
```

Comment: I don't think you need the comparisons, could just use the truth value of `a` and `b`.